# NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage() not remove shadow line after xamarin.forms 4.5

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage() not remove shadow line on IOS after xamarin.forms 4.5.
What is the new way to do it?

I tried all of these, but not works.

```
   protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
        NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
    }
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
        NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
        NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
    }
```

Comment: Hi , that's strange . I also reproduced that in my local site . Then you can dowgrade Xamrin Forms to 4.4 version to make it works first .

Comment: I have submitted it to Github here : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10337, we can follow it up there later .

Comment: Hi, thanks. Im using this now https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/navigation-bar-separator but on some pages its not working. My page hierarchy like this Navigation page > Tabbed page > navigation page > content pages. The problem on the first page of tabbed page which has no back button.

Comment: Great , that's a good solution ! I think if want all pages work , need to keep the page  navigating from Navigation Page and need to use `Navigation.PushAsync` to navigate .

Comment: Yeah i know but in this flow its broken on first page of tabbed page. Its my new problem.

Comment: Okey , you mean Tabbed page not works by using this way to hide shadow line ,Right ? If setting `Navigation Page` as `Root Page` for application , not need to add other `Navigation Page` for `Child Page` . Such as this View level :  **Navigation Page > Tabbed page > content pages**. Becuse the rest of `Child Page`(*Content Page*) all will show the `Navigation Bar` if set `Navigation Page` as `Root Page` for Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue like this:

My custom navigation page

```
        public CustomNavigationPage(Xamarin.Forms.Page root) : base(root)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        On<iOS>().SetHideNavigationBarSeparator(true);
    }
```

And on navigation page renderer

```
 public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        if (Element is Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage navigationPage)
        {
            if (navigationPage.OnThisPlatform().HideNavigationBarSeparator())
            {
                if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
                {
                    NavigationBar.StandardAppearance.ShadowColor = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Awesome ! Glad find the solution . Remember to mark it later when you can :-)